# zope and tal, repeat function

Tags: repeat

```
<div tal:define="number python: 1">
<tal:block repeat="item s_items">
    <div tal:define="number python: number + 1">     
         <div tal:content="python: number">none</div>
     </div> 
</tal:block>
</div>
```

Hi, always show 2.
but I would like to show 2 3 4 5 ...
How to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for the delay, you could do something like.

```
<div tal:define="global number python: 1">
<tal:block repeat="item s_items">
<div tal:define="global number python: number + 1">     
     <div tal:content="python: number">none</div>
 </div> 
</tal:block>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I'm a bit late ;-)

Wouldn't this be better solved with repeat variables?

```
<tal:loop repeat="item s_items">
    <div tal:content="repeat/item/number">1</div>
</tal:loop>
```

("loop" instead of "block" is just a matter of taste ...)

The name after "repeat" is the name of your iterator variable "item"; "number" starts with 1, "index" starts with 0 (there are more).

Comment: This answer is perfect in case of generation serial number for records.